# div position absolute... overflow-y:auto and then vertical scrollbar covers some of the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with absolute position

inside some other divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/d8GYk/

```
 <div style="position: absolute; 
display: block; 
outline: 0px;
 margin: 0px; 
 padding: 0px; 
 top: 0; 
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 11px; 
 font-family: arial; 
 cursor: default; 
 border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170); 
 overflow-x: hidden; white-space: pre; 
 overflow-y: auto; 
 left: 0px; 
 height: 132px;"><div>a                             a END</div><div>ab</div><div>ab</div><div>ab</div><div>ab</div><div>ab</div><div>ab</div><div>ab</div><div>ab</div><div>ab</div><div>ab</div><div>ab</div><div>ab</div></div>
```

As you can see the first div is not completely visible
That's because the vertical scroll bar covers it.

If I set overflow-y:scroll. The problem goes away.

However I don't want to do it because this div is autogenerated (via javascript) and in many cases I don't need the vertical scroll bar (for example if the list has one or two or three items)

Can somebody suggest how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Please have some mercy and don't use inline css

Comment: why are you <pre> formatting all this data? What are you really trying to do, that you've decided to solve by using this div solution? (because I strongly suspect there's a better solution already out there, and you're asking us to solve the wrong problem).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am pre-formatting  because its content needs to take into account spaces. i Just need a div to wrap some other pre-formatted divs (a bit like a list). I need the scrollbar not to hide anything of the content

Comment: Opera does the layout properly and widens the div so that content *and* scrollbar show up. In what browser (version) do you experience this problem?

Comment: What do you expect? An `overflow-x: hidden; white-space: pre;` can always lead to hidden content if the width of the div can be limited by something. Just set `overflow-x: auto` as well, or use `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Comment: Seriously, frame your question properly...what you want ? what are your conditions ?

Comment: @Bergi Chrome is the browser I am using. overflow-x:hidden is because I never want any horizontal scroll bar. The width should take as much space as it needs

Comment: @Ani c'mon why vote it down ? surely I could phrase it better but some people are getting what I am asking...

Comment: @Ani fair enough. I am sorry I should have explained myself better. Nonetheless I am glad I got enough help to get through this issue

Comment: Happy to help...If my answer were actually any kind of help :P

Comment: @Ani I am working on your suggestion... still struggling a bit but getting there ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the scrollbar may or may not show, use a content container with a wrapper that may or may not scroll. html:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="entries">
       <div>ab                          a</div>
       <div>ab</div>
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.container {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.entries div {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Demonstrator: http://jsfiddle.net/gFrbM

That said, if you absolute need `pre` white space handling, AND your lines are very long, you'll either need to turn on scroll for both directions, not just `y`, and that's a good indication that the way you're trying to present content is not a good way to go about it. The UX will be poor for your users, and depending on the content you're listing in these entry divs, there will be much better ways to show that data.

Comment: Thanks but as you can see from your jsfiddle the div container then takes far too much horizontal space.

Comment: right, so you give the div of class `container` an explicit width if you need it to have that, and then we immediately run into the problem for which I added the comment starting with "That said, ..."

Answer (score 0):

Du you really need "white-space: pre;"?
If you remove this part i think it is going to work

Comment: Karzin - yes I need white-space:pre

Answer (score 0):

Add this to css

```
{padding-right: 20px;}
```

Reason: The border of the scroll is covering your div text. you need to give some space for the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/d8GYk/3/

Comment: interesting but who tells you that the scroll bar is going to take always at most 20px. Also padding-right would be applied always even if the scroll-bar is not present...

Comment: @Zo72 - Sorry, I misunderstood your question. What do you exactly want ?

Comment: Also, I didn't mean exactly 20px. that was a broader value to make you understand the problem

Comment: almost... the only thing is that if the div fits the vertical size (I don't get the scrollbar so I still have the 20px padding right which is a bit annoying) see: http://jsfiddle.net/9PxPF/

Answer (score 0):

Use a margin-right for each div inside the container:

```
.container div{margin:0 20px 0 0}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Karzin/d8GYk/2/

Comment: thanks but who tells you that the scroll bar is going to take always at most 20px. Alsom argin-right would be applied always even if the scroll-bar is not present which is not good